# An Up and Down Series 00,50,33,25 . .

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I won't provide a hint this time. This one is OEIS-proof (similar to waterproof :D) too. Twenty terms and guess its logic only.

> 00,50,33,25,20,16,14,12,11,10,90,83,76,71,66,62,58,55,52,50

Comment: Is it important that it's `09` and not just `9`?

Comment: @EngineerToast mistyped. it's 90

Comment: @EngineerToast edited.

Comment: OK, good. I imagine you wanted it to be harder but not *that* hard.

Comment: @EngineerToast depends...

Comment: Is it important that it's `00` and not just `0`?

Comment: I like this, but I actually think ADG1 was better and harder (though the hint might have been too much!)

Comment: Too easy IMO. 50, 33, 25, 20 is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To get the nth term, do 1/n and take the first two significant figures after the decimal point (not including leading zeros)

Comment: Arg!  Beat me. :)

Comment: anything that helped you most?

Comment: @ADG "50,33,25" was pretty recognisable. I then just ran a short python script to make sure the numbers matched up for the rest of the series :-)

Answer (score 2):

> First two decimal points ignoring zeros of 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4...